# Having clause with aggregate and NOT IN doesn't apply both as expected

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select trees from the following sample that have had the Vigor value 6,8 or 9 for the past three years straight. So, in the below grid I would want all rows with TreeID 2 and 3, but not any with TreeID 1.

```
PlotID    ObsYear TreeID Vigor
MACFI0407 2020    1      8
MACFI0407 2021    1      8
MACFI0407 2022    1      8
MACFI0407 2020    2      1
MACFI0407 2021    2      1
MACFI0407 2022    2      8
MACFI0407 2020    3      1
MACFI0407 2021    3      1
MACFI0407 2022    3      1
```

This is what I thought I wanted, but it doesn't seem like mySQL is using the 'AND' to mean BOTH. This is leaving out TreeID 3 since it has a count of 3 (but Vigor value was 1)

```
SELECT PlotID, TreeID, Vigor, count(*) c
FROM tblTreeInfo
GROUP BY PlotID, TreeID, Vigor
HAVING (c < 3 AND Vigor NOT IN (6, 8, 9))
```

So I tried this, but this leaves out TreeID 2, since it has Vigor 8, but only for 1 year.

```
SELECT PlotID, TreeID, Vigor, count(*) c
FROM tblTreeInfo
WHERE Vigor NOT IN (6, 8, 9)
GROUP BY PlotID, TreeID, Vigor
HAVING (c < 3)
```

How can I get rows with both vigor not 6,8,9 AND c<3?  Thank you!

Comment: The query is malformed and can run in MySQL 5.7 (you should upgrade). All columns, not mentioned in the `GROUP BY` clause should be aggregated in the select list. However `ObsYear` is not. Please fix the query.

Comment: OK, I removed ObsYear from the select

Comment: If you want to include the `count(*)` = 3 then you can change to `c <= 3` (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dxZCzkF8)).

Comment: that have had the Vigor value 6,8 or 9' - I think there should be a NOT in this statement. Also can you publish your desired result based on the published sample.

Comment: You have not given us all information. The "past three years" are the years 2020 to 2022 obviously, because now is 2023. Okay. In your sample data, each treeid has one entry in each of these years. Is it possible for a treeid to have two entries in one year? Is it possible for a treeid not to have a row in one of these years? If so, and if a treeid only has rows in 2022, it must be shown, because it doesn't have the desired vigors in those three years straight. Correct?

Comment: "select trees from the following sample **that have had the Vigor value 6,8 or 9** for the past three years straight" means that you want only TreeID  =1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the last three years (2020 to 2022). Getting these rows is the first step. Then you want to omit tree IDs that had vigor 6, 8 or 9 in each of these years. Find these IDs, by counting distinct years in which these vigors occured. Then select the rows omitting these IDs.

```
with rows_of_interest as
(
  select *
  from mytable
  where obsyear between year(curdate()) - 3 and year(curdate()) - 1
)
select *
from rows_of_interest
where treeid not in
(
  select treeid
  from rows_of_interest
  where vigor in (6, 8, 9)
  group by treeid
  having count(distinct obsyear) = 3
)
order by treeid, obsyear;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/DeRhqRoX

Comment: I finally figured out why I wasn't getting the result that I wanted with this query.  I have a tree that ONLY has observations for 2021 and 2022, and they are both Vigor 6.  Unfortunately this tree isn't picked up, because it doesn't have a Vigor other than 6.  However it hasn't been marked as 6 for 3 years yet.  So not quite the query I was hoping for, but close!

Answer (score 0):

```
## TREES THAT ARE NOT VIGOROUS OVER PAST 3 YEARS
SELECT
  T.*
FROM mytable AS T
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT treeid
        FROM mytable
        GROUP BY treeid
        HAVING (MAX(CASE WHEN obsyear = year(curdate()) - 3 AND vigor IN (6,8,9) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
              + MAX(CASE WHEN obsyear = year(curdate()) - 2 AND vigor IN (6,8,9) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
              + MAX(CASE WHEN obsyear = year(curdate()) - 1 AND vigor IN (6,8,9) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) = 3
        ) AS VIGOR ON T.TREEID = VIGOR.TREEID
WHERE VIGOR.TREEID IS NULL
```

| plotid | obsyear | treeid | vigor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MACFI0407 | 2020 | 2 | 1 |
| MACFI0407 | 2021 | 2 | 1 |
| MACFI0407 | 2022 | 2 | 8 |
| MACFI0407 | 2020 | 3 | 1 |
| MACFI0407 | 2021 | 3 | 1 |
| MACFI0407 | 2022 | 3 | 1 |
| MACFI0407 | 2020 | 4 | 6 |
| MACFI0407 | 2020 | 4 | 8 |
| MACFI0407 | 2020 | 4 | 9 |

```
## TREES THAT ARE VIGOROUS OVER PAST 3 YEARS
SELECT
  T.*
FROM mytable AS T
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT treeid
        FROM mytable
        GROUP BY treeid
        HAVING (MAX(CASE WHEN obsyear = year(curdate()) - 3 AND vigor IN (6,8,9) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
              + MAX(CASE WHEN obsyear = year(curdate()) - 2 AND vigor IN (6,8,9) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
              + MAX(CASE WHEN obsyear = year(curdate()) - 1 AND vigor IN (6,8,9) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) = 3
        ) AS VIGOR ON T.TREEID = VIGOR.TREEID
```

| plotid | obsyear | treeid | vigor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MACFI0407 | 2020 | 1 | 8 |
| MACFI0407 | 2021 | 1 | 8 |
| MACFI0407 | 2022 | 1 | 8 |
| MACFI0407 | 2020 | 5 | 6 |
| MACFI0407 | 2021 | 5 | 8 |
| MACFI0407 | 2022 | 5 | 9 |
| MACFI0407 | 2023 | 5 | 9 |
| MACFI0407 | 2020 | 5 | 6 |
| MACFI0407 | 2020 | 5 | 8 |
| MACFI0407 | 2022 | 5 | 9 |
| MACFI0407 | 2022 | 5 | 9 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9WNrWNsL)

Answer (score -1):

A Simple way to do it, is to include `count(*) = 3` since only Trees with last 3 years having Vigor IN (6, 8, 9) must be ignored :

```
with cte as (
  SELECT PlotID, TreeID, Vigor, count(*) c
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY PlotID, TreeID, Vigor
  HAVING (c <= 3 AND Vigor NOT IN (6, 8, 9))
)
select t.*
from mytable t
inner join cte c on c.TreeID = t.TreeID
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/kFLsg_BU)

Comment: this does not guarantee that all 3 years are included in the count, only that 3 rows are considered i.e. it fails to do this part of the requirement "**for the past three years straight.**"